# Python Stored Procedure Error

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures

I am getting an error when I try to execute a stored procedure in python.  I am using python 2.7 and mysql.
The stored procedure works when I call it from mysql workbench or if i call from the command line.
Here is the code.

```
 class db_conn:
     def __init__(self,db_name):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'test', password = 'test', host = 'localhost', database = 'test')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        self.return_data = []


def select_procedure(self, proc):
    print(proc)
    self.cursor.callproc(proc,'')
    self.conn.commit()
    return cursor.stored_results()
```

I get the following error.

```
1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Here is the stored procedure.  Nothing much to it.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_info`()
BEGIN
    Select  id, fname,lname
    From    name_table
    where   display = 0 limit 1;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The issue is python's callproc is expecting a tuple.  So I added a variable to my stored procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_info`(id int)
```

Then added a tuple of nothing to.

```
self.cursor.callproc(proc,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing closing info for the SP:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_info`()
BEGIN
    Select  id, fname,lname
    From    name_table
    where   display = 0 limit 1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I copied your code.  Same error.  I am using mysql workbench is that the issue?

Comment: @user3525290 no, i tested the code on mysql workbench ; You are getting the exact same error message?

Comment: Exact same error. “You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1”. I am using MySQL workbench 5.2. I am not at my desk now. But I think that is the version.